# How to put an class inside an object while Serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

**I have two classes made as:**

```
public class ipAddress
{
    public object ip { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ipAddress conditions { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public Boolean enabled { get; set; }
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
}
```

**My code to create/assign values to this is:**

```
        Rule new_rule = new Rule();
        ipAddress ip_info = new ipAddress();
        ip_info.ip = new { ipAddress = "34.5.6.7.8" };
        new_rule.name = "test";
        new_rule.conditions = ip_info;
        new_rule.action = "ALLOW";
        new_rule.enabled = true;
        new_rule.statusCode = "FORBIDDEN_403";
        var rule_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new_rule);
```

***after serializing I get this output***

`{"name":"test","conditions":{"ip":{"ipAddress":"34.5.6.7.8"}},"action":"ALLOW","enabled":true,"statusCode":"FORBIDDEN_403"}`

***While my expected output is:***

`{"name":"test","conditions":[{"ip":{"ipAddress":"34.5.6.7.8"}}],"action":"ALLOW","enabled":true,"statusCode":"FORBIDDEN_403"}`

**so the only difference is the extra object wrapped around the conditions' values.
How can I accomplish this? Tried different things but didn't get there.
Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to get your expected output, your `ipAddress` should be an array.

```
public class Rule
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ipAddress[] conditions { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public Boolean enabled { get; set; }
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
}

Rule new_rule = new Rule();
ipAddress ip_info = new ipAddress();
ip_info.ip = new { ipAddress = "34.5.6.7.8" };
new_rule.name = "test";
new_rule.conditions = new ipAddress[] { ip_info };
new_rule.action = "ALLOW";
new_rule.enabled = true;
new_rule.statusCode = "FORBIDDEN_403";
var rule_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new_rule);
```

The result that u will obtain from this is

```
{"name":"test","conditions":[{"ip":{"ipAddress":"34.5.6.7.8"}}],"action":"ALLOW","enabled":true,"statusCode":"FORBIDDEN_403"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public ipAddress conditions { get; set; }
```

The above statement means `conditions` is an object and objects are represented by `{ }`. If you are expecting it to be a list/array of objects (represented by `[ ]`), then you will need to define your conditions as an array/list item

```
public List<ipAddress> conditions { get; set; }
```

Your assignment object for conditions should look like this,

```
new_rule.conditions = new List<ipAddress>() { ip_info };
```

This will produce the result you want. Also, According to the naming conventions, your class name and variable names should start with UpperCase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You want the conditions to be an array
So you need to declare public IP addresses[] conditions

You also assigned an object to it and that's the output you get
If you want the json to have an array output you have to declare it as an array

Comment: If I change  `public ipAddress conditions { get; set; }` to `public ipAddress[] conditions { get; set; }` then what would i write for this ? `new_rule.conditions = ip_info;`